# Is it good practice that creating a new branch for unit testing in Git?

Tags: java, git, unit-testing, git-branch

For example I have class `A` and I have `feature/A` branch for implementing class `A` .

Should I create a new feature branch like `feature/TestA` for implementing unit test of class `A` ?

Or should I implement unit tests of class `A` in same branch `feature/A`?

And what is best practice of this problem?

Comment: I think, this is an opinion based question.

Comment: You write the test before or along side with the code being tested. This is only possible on the same branch.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the best approach here will be to implement the unit test in the same branch. It has few benefits, for example:

- While doing a code-review, unit-test can help understand better the
  feature.
- Sometimes unit-tests makes you change your code, and if you are on the same branch it will be much easier.

I have many more examples :)